# How C++ check condition and throw exception like Java Spring Assert

Tags: c++, boost

Is there a standard way to do something like this?

1. Available for release mode (NDEBUG defined)
2. Throw exception when checking failure.

Standard library or boost are preferable.

---

To make it clear, the 'assertion' (maybe a different term) I use here, is particularly about **runtime problem**, not the programming problem, something like [Spring Assert](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Assert.html) in Java world.

[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694604.aspx) is good candidate, but it is for testing purpose.

Comment: Note that while there are valid reasons to do this, exceptions thrown by such an assert implementation should be considered 'uncatchable'. In particular, a program must never (!) catch an exception thrown by such an assert and then continue normal execution afterwards. This is the fundamental distinction between assertions (which always indicate a programming error of some sorts) and normal exceptions (which can be triggered by runtime conditions outside the programmer's control).

Comment: Actually, the 'assertion' here is about the 'runtime conditions', not the programming error. Maybe we should use a different word for this, what's the term in C++? So in runtime, I want to be able to check a condition if it doesn't reach, then throws an exception.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely [not an assertion then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)#Comparison_with_error_handling). Assert always implies that things are screwed up so badly that you cannot continue normal execution. I guess you simply want a macro that checks a condition and then throws if it's violated. You might want to edit the question to avoid that misunderstanding.

Comment: @ComicSansMS description changed.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's much clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some of my projects I use:

```
void ASSERT(const bool cond, const std::string& text)
{
    if (!cond)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(text);
    }
}
```

If you want more information you could use a macro to call the actual function like so:

```
void ASSERT(const bool cond, const std::string& text, const std::string& file, const int line)
{
    if (!cond)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(text + ". In file: " + file + " on line: " + std::to_string(line));
    }
}

#define ASSERT(cond, text) ASSERT(cond, text, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

void ASSERT(const bool cond, const std::string& text, const std::string& file, const int line)
{
    if (!cond)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(text + ". In file: " + file + " on line: " + std::to_string(line));
    }
}

#define ASSERT(cond, text) ASSERT(cond, text, __FILE__, __LINE__)

int main()
{
    ASSERT(false, "example text");
}
```

Will result in:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  example text. In file: example.cpp on line: 17
Aborted
```

**Update:**

To get the same behaviour as a normal `assert`, i.e., unconditional termination of the program you can call `std::abort()` (from `<cstdlib>`) instead of using `throw`:

```
void ASSERT(const bool cond, const std::string& text, const std::string& file, const int line)
{
    if (!cond)
    {
        std::cout << text << ". In file: " << file << " on line: " << line << std::endl;
        std::abort();
    }
}

#define ASSERT(cond, text) ASSERT(cond, text, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Comment: Looks good. If I don't what to terminate the program, then simply use std::exception instead of runtime_error.

I don't know why std or boost doesn't provide this kind of facilities.

Comment: [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) seems to be a bad fit here. [`std::logic_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) might be a better candidate, as assertions typically do _not_ check conditions depending on runtime behavior.

Comment: If you don't want the program to terminate you should wrap the assertion in a `try-catch` block.

Comment: Yes, of course, that's the purpose for the requirement :)

Comment: @ComicSansMS That is a valid point. A possible solution could be to have more than one `ASSERT`-like functions.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I have updated the answer with a solution that users abort